# Find string and print it and the column value beside it

Tags: python, regex, string, csv

I have many csv files. Each has a headline cell "Total" with a number in the column immediately to the right.

Unfortunately, these cells are not always in the same place in the csv file.

My goal is to create code that isolates/finds these two relevant cells no matter where they are and print them.

I have figured ways to do it when I know where they are, but I want one way that can achieve this no matter the location (even if in column headers. I am using pandas, dfs.)

Thanks

Edit:
In its raw form the df appears as so.
A summary table with strings in col1 and data in col2 for about 15 rows.
Occasionally, this data will be spread out over fewer rows and more columns.

The "total" that I am looking to isolate is always in the above section

The rest if a large data table of hundreds of rows and 15 or so columns.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your `dataframe` looks like?

Comment: This is not a `pandas` question. Pandas is about applying systematic operations on a structured dataset. It looks to me as if your problem is that you don't have any structure in the first place.. ("BS in, BS out"). Is this more of a `regex` exercise? Can you show 1-2 examples of your csv(!) files?

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` is not the best way to achieve this goal. You could use the built-in python `csv` library:

```
import csv

with open('C:\\path\\to\\file', newline = "") as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'))
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if (data [i] == "Total"):
            print(data [i + 1])
```

Comment: Luke, almost there! I get an error as follows for "for i in range(len(list))" : object of type 'type' has no len()

Comment: @dandel1 I've just edited. Instead of putting `range(len(data))`, I put `range(len(list))` which doesn't make any sense. Try the new code